# Unable to install laravel/sail due to incompatible versions it seems

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-sail

I'm trying to install `laravel/sail` into an existing project, which doesn't appear to have had it installed before. This project is normally run on vagrant I believe.

I'm trying to get it running on WSL2, using Laravel Sail. I'm also not entirely sure if that's the best approach in my case.

My understanding is that I can use sail to get the project running via docker, with minimal setup and configuration.

I seem to be getting an error when I try to install sail via composer. These are the instructions I'm following: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-sail-into-existing-applications

Here's the error:

```
$ composer require laravel/sail --dev
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
Using version ^1.13 for laravel/sail
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/sail
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/sail ^1.13 -> satisfiable by laravel/sail[v1.13.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - laravel/sail[v1.13.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/contracts ^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/sail:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/sail:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I'm not entirely sure how to interpret this, but it looks like the version that is attempting to be installed is not compatible with another required package.

##### `composer.json` file:

```json
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
                "framework",
                "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
                "php": "^7.4",
                "composer-runtime-api": "^2.0",
                "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.6",
                "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
                "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
                "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3",
                "laravel/framework": "6.*",
                "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.5",
                "laravel/passport": "9.4.*",
                "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
                "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
                "nexmo/laravel": "^2.4",
                "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "1.7.*",
                "spatie/laravel-uptime-monitor": "^3.7",
                "vonage/client": "^2.4"
        },
        "require-dev": {
                "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
                "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.8",
                "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
                "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
                "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
                "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.1"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "database",
                        "app/Http/Controllers",
                        "app/Console/Commands"
                ],
                "psr-4": {
                        "App\\": "app/"
                }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
                "psr-4": {
                        "Tests\\": "tests/"
                }
        },
        "extra": {
                "laravel": {
                        "dont-discover": []
                }
        },
        "scripts": {
                "post-root-package-install": [
                        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "@php artisan key:generate"
                ],
                "post-autoload-dump": [
                        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                        "@php artisan package:discover"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "platform": {
                        "php": "7.4"
                },
                "preferred-install": "dist",
                "sort-packages": true,
                "optimize-autoloader": true
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you **won't** be able to work with [`laravel/sail`](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/sail) based on your current Laravel framework version.

#### Explanation:

[laravel/sail="1.13"](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/sail#v1.13.0) **requires** [`illuminate/contracts`](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/contracts): ^8.0|^9.0`

Now, ask yourself a question, what packages depend on `illuminate/contracts` in *Laravel v6*?

Command: `composer depends illuminate/contracts`

Output:

```sh
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
fideloper/proxy    4.4.1     requires  illuminate/contracts (^5.0|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0)
laravel/framework  v6.18.43  replaces  illuminate/contracts (self.version)
laravel/tinker     v1.0.10   requires  illuminate/contracts (~5.1|^6.0)
```

Based on the *output* above, you kind of realize that the **common** *illuminate/contracts* version between all dependents is `^6.0`.

With that in mind, you would normally need to install a `laravel/sail` version that requires `illuminate/contracts`: ^6.0`

Unfortunately, that **isn't** possible. This is so because even the first `laravel/sail` version ([`dev-develop`](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/sail#dev-develop)) **requires** `illuminate/contracts`: ^8.0|^9.0|^10.0.

Now, the most reasonable option would be to first **upgrade** the package(s) that depend on *illuminate/contracts* in your project. Among all 3 packages in the *output* above, is the Laravel framework. Sadly enough, the first framework version that meets the `illuminate/contracts: ^8.0|^9.0` requirement is **[`laravel/framework v8.0.0`](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework#v8.0.0)**. If that is something you would consider, then you may want to look at the [Laravel 8 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade).

#### Possible solution:

Considering that [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail) is simply a tool to provide you with a starting point for building a Laravel application using PHP, MySQL, and Redis without requiring prior Docker experience, there are other tools that can get the job done in a similar fashion.

One tool I may suggest is [Laradock](http://laradock.io/).

---

If you have enough docker experience, you could even roll out your own docker set-up from scratch with the help of readily available public official docker images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

Comment: Awesome, that clears it up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this and avoid the incompatibility of certain dependencies, you can run:

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev --ignore-platform-reqs
```

But it's not a very good practice.

Comment: I tried this, and it seems I'm getting the same error